Needs help understanding this breaker: Chint NB1-63 C50. Confusing (63 or 50)
I'm trying to understand information on this AC breaker.(See picture)
Is this Rated for 50 amps or 63 amps?  Does the "C50" stand for Current? If you think it's 50 amps, how do you know this?  I wasn't able to find any information on line.
Also, I noticed there's those 2 arrows that point up and down... and a "-" and "0" next to each arrow... Does that mean it does NOT offer bi-directional protection.
Thanks for your help.


Just a quick comment: that's not a minus and a zero but a zero and a one (sorta, the usual symbol of on-off, a circle with a vertical line inside).


Is this Rated for 50 amps or 63 amps? Does the "C50" stand for Current?

The C means this is a type C MCB. This is an introductory guide to MCB types, also known as tripping curves.
It is common to write the type letter and current rating together. So C50 means a type C MCB with 50 A rating.

Also, I noticed there's those 2 arrows that point up and down... and a "-" and "0" next to each arrow

This is telling you the operating handles need to be up for on and down for off (or in the direction of the arrows if not installed vertically as pictured).

Does that mean it does NOT offer bi-directional protection.

It offers two-pole switching, as shown on the wiring diagram on the right. Is that what you meant by bi-directional protection? It has magnetic (short-circuit) and thermal (overload) protection on both poles. (This earlier question discusses breakers where one pole (typically used for neutral) is switched but not protected, i.e. has no current measurement.)
Chint have their own guide to the information printed on their MCBs.

I wasn't able to find any information on line.

Searching for chint nb1-63 seems to give useful links. This Chint Global page has documents for both the IEC and the pictured UL versions.

And the number "63" in NB1-63 series name comes from 63 A being the highest current rating available in the series, while "C50" is the actual trip point of this model.

A quick search with Google shows that the C50 indicates it is a 50 ampere breaker. NB 1-63 is the basic part number.
